# Uptime since boot excluding sleep for osx yosemite?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

How can a I get the total uptime since boot (excluding the sleep time)?

I can use the `uptime` command which shows how long since the last boot, but this does not differentiate between active use and sleep or hibernation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no simple command executed in Terminal to get your desired result.

Here is an example for a workaround to get the uptime and the sleep time(s):

```
uptime && pmset -g log|grep 'date'|grep -E ' Wake | Sleep '|grep -v 'Dark Wake'
```

with date: dd/mm/yy (example: 23/07/15)

Example (10.9.5 Virtual Machine):

```
machinename:~ user$ uptime && pmset -g log|grep '23/07/15'|grep -E ' Wake | Sleep '|grep -v 'Dark Wake'
14:59  up  1:09, 3 users, load averages: 0.58 0.47 0.51
23/07/15 13:51:39 GMT+2  Sleep                  Software Sleep pid=90: Using AC                                             10 secs   
23/07/15 13:51:49 GMT+2  Wake                   Wake [CDNVA] due to power-button/User: Using AC                             149 secs  
23/07/15 13:54:18 GMT+2  Sleep                  Software Sleep pid=90: Using AC                                             91 secs   
23/07/15 13:55:49 GMT+2  Wake                   Wake [CDNVA] due to power-button/User: Using AC                             1872 secs 
23/07/15 14:27:01 GMT+2  Sleep                  Software Sleep pid=90: Using AC                                             7 secs    
23/07/15 14:27:08 GMT+2  Wake                   Wake [CDNVA] due to power-button/User: Using AC
```

Now do the math and calculate the non-sleep uptime. (6540 secs - 108 secs = 6432 secs).

Depending on your operating system and the hibernation mode you set, you may have to alter the grep part in the above command. Check `pmset -g log` for the appropriate strings. You also may omit the ' Wake ' part of the command to simplfy the output.

Answer (score 2):

execute the following script with `python3`

```py
# imports
import os
from datetime import datetime

# global declarations
sleepAndWakes = []
cummulatedAwakeTime =  datetime.strptime('0001-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
previousSleepAndWakeWithTime = None

resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBoot = None

class SleepAndWakeWithTime:
    def __init__(self, dateTime, actionName):
        self.dateTime = dateTime
        self.actionName = actionName


# reading log messages vi pmset
stream = os.popen('pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  " -e " DarkWake  " -e " ShutdownCause " -e " Start "')
lines = stream.readlines()

# parse pmset lines and store them in an array of event and date-time
for line in lines:
    #print('line: ' + line)
    dateTimeStr =  line[:19]
    actionName = line[26:34].strip()
    datetimeObject = datetime.strptime(dateTimeStr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sleepAndWakes.append(SleepAndWakeWithTime(datetimeObject, actionName))

# read array and calcualate the total wake time (all the times between sleeps)
for index, sleepAndWakeWithTime in enumerate(sleepAndWakes):
    #print(sleepAndWakeWithTime.dateTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + ' ' + sleepAndWakeWithTime.actionName)
    if index > 0: 
        previousSleepAndWakeWithTime = sleepAndWakes[index-1].dateTime
        timeDifference = sleepAndWakeWithTime.dateTime - previousSleepAndWakeWithTime
        if sleepAndWakeWithTime.actionName == 'Sleep' or sleepAndWakeWithTime.actionName == 'Shutdown': 
            cummulatedAwakeTime += timeDifference; #print(timeDifference)

        # ask to reset statistics after boot (and then reset if 'y' was typed)
        if sleepAndWakeWithTime.actionName == 'Start':
            if resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBoot == None:
                resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBootAnswer = input("Do you want to calculate/cummulate the total awaketime since the last boot [y] or the total awake time [n]?")
                if resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBootAnswer == 'y': resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBoot = 'y'
                elif resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBootAnswer == 'n': resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBoot = 'n'
                else: 
                    print('insufficient answer assuming yes')
                    resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBoot = 'y'
            if resetAwakeStatisticsByLastBoot == 'y': cummulatedAwakeTime =  datetime.strptime('0001-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# add time since last sleep
cummulatedAwakeTime += (datetime.now() - previousSleepAndWakeWithTime)

# reduece the inital minimum date value
cummulatedAwakeTime -= datetime.strptime('0001-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print('Total awake time : ' + str(cummulatedAwakeTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script, that calculates the real uptime.

Example output:

```
2023-06-25 17:30:26 Boot
2023-06-25 19:10:16 Sleep
------------------- 5990 sec
2023-06-25 22:15:39 Wake
2023-06-26 00:31:25 Now
------------------- 14136 sec
Real uptime: 3.92 hours
```

Usage: 1) Save to `realuptime.sh` 2) `chmod +x realuptime.sh` 3) `./realuptime.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get the boot time in timestamp format (for calculations) and datetime format (for comparison).
boottime_timestamp=$(sysctl kern.boottime | awk -F'[=,]' '{print $2}' | tr -d ' \n')
boottime_date=$(date -r $boottime_timestamp +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
echo "$boottime_date Boot"

# Timestamp from which we monitor the Sleep and Wake events
last_timestamp=$boottime_timestamp

(         # Start a subshell
IFS=$'\n' # Set the Internal Field Separator temporarily

# The "events" variable is an array, where we collect every Sleep and Wake events in "Y-m-d H:M:S Eventname" format.

# sleep and wake events
events=( $(pmset -g log | grep -e "Clamshell Sleep" -e "\tWake from Deep Idle" -e "FullWake from Deep Idle" | cut -d' ' -f1,2,4 | awk -v start="$boottime_date" '$0 >= start') )

# current time
events+=(  $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S Now") )

sum=0  # Collects the number of seconds when the computer is awake

for line in "${events[@]}"  # Loop through events array
do
    echo $line

    date=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1,2)
    timestamp=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "$date" "+%s")

    # If this is a Boot or Wake event, we note its time (timestamp)
    if [[ $line == *"Wake"* ]]
    then
        last_timestamp=$timestamp
    fi

    # If it is a Sleep event when wakefulness ends, 
    # then we calculate the seconds that have passed since the previous recorded time.
    # We also add the time that has passed until the current moment.
    if [[ $line == *"Sleep"* || $line == *"Now"* ]]
    then
        count=$(expr $timestamp - $last_timestamp)
        sum=$(expr $sum + $count)
        echo "------------------- $sum sec"
    fi
done

hours=$(echo "scale=2; $sum / 3600" | bc -l)
echo "Real uptime: $hours hours"
)
```